# Camera Preview freeze after PermissionMessage

Tags: android

i hope someone can help me. 
If I press the take Picture Button, I get asked for the storage permissions. It doesnt matter if i press deny or allow, the CameraPreview freeze after the message 
disappear.

I found out, that the onResume Methode is called after I press deny or allow. So here is my Code of the onResume Method:

```
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);

        mCameraSurfaceView = new CameraSurfaceView(mFragmentView.getContext(),mCamera, LiveViewFragment.this);
        mCameraPreviewLayout.addView(mCameraSurfaceView,0);
        mCamera.startPreview();
```

edit: Code from surfaceChanged in CameraSurfaceView:

```
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        camera.startPreview();
```

If I go to my Home Screen an open the App again everything works fine and the View doesnt freeze.

Comment: i think the problem is in your onResume().i told about onResume() of your 
CameraSurfaceView() class.put this method also.

Comment: hi, Im my CameraSurfaceView there is no onResume. It extends SurfaceView and implements SurfaceHolderCallback. But the on surfaceChanged Method is called if the onResume gets called. i added the code below.

Comment: then you have to Add onResume() & onPause() in your Class.it is required.i am also developing camera App.without those both method my Camera was also freezed but not now [After adding both method]

Comment: if you take separate class for CameraPreview then you can not put onResume() & onPause.

Comment: and also you are not in Right way.because when your App will Open your CameraPreview is set in your View.and what you did after Press Dialog Button. you did again set your CameraPreview into your View.that is the Reason of your FREEZE

Comment: thank you that solved my Problem. But now the app crash if i go to my home screen and open the app again.

Comment: ok i know. why it's happened.i think you did not release the Camera Preview when you Quit the App.

Comment: you put all your Class code.and i will tell you.what you need to do.OK